# How to start random python file with python

Tags: python

I have 10 python file (1.py, 2.py, 3.py .... 10.py) i want to start random with python script, with while true. For ex. script start random py file (4.py) after finish the commands start again new random file (1.py) I want it to spin like this forever.

I try with this command but not working.

```
while True :
    p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'randint(1,10).py'])
```

Script give error

> python: can't open file '<randint<1,3>>.py':

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
while True :
    p = subprocess.Popen(['python', str(randint(1,10))+'.py'])
```

`randint(1,3)` is a function, not a string, so it should be outside `''`s. Then, I use `str()` to convert the number returned by `randint` to a string. Finally, I added `+` to concatenate `str(randint(1,3))` and `'.py'`! Also, if you have 10 files, then the second parameter of `randint` should be 10.

Comment: Or better use an f-string: `p = subprocess.Popen(['python', f'{randint(1,10)}.py'])`

Comment: Hello, first of all thank you very much for your help @Yulia V . How can I wait for a python script to finish its task? In this way, the python file is opened unlimitedly. Temporarily because I know the process takes an estimated 70 seconds I used this code: `p = subprocess.Popen(['python', str(randint(1,3))+'.py'])
        time.sleep(70)
        p.terminate()`

Comment: @EnesAksu would you like to ask it as a separate question? Quick answer though: if your script files contain functions, you can import the files as modules and call the functions they contain instead of launching separate python processes. This might help. If not, please ask a separate question :)